# Data Category mapping to an Account field?

Tags: fields, articles, data-category, categories

I inherited this Service Cloud setup where accounts all have a picklist field called Level with options 1, 2, 3, and then there is a Data Category called Level with options Level 1, Level 2, Level 3.

Customer users whose account has the Level 1 field can see **all** articles, except those with the Level 2 or Level 3 Data Category.

Customer users whose account has the Level 2 field can see all articles, except those with the Level 1 or Level 3 Data Category.

Customer users whose account has the Level 3 field can see all articles, except those with the Level 1 or Level 1 Data Category.

the client wants me to add a Level 4 now and in order to do that I'm trying to figure out how this was accomplished. there are no data category mappings or anything like that.

Comment: This sounds like it could have been done with the out of box security layers. But if the logic follows the same as the others, you'll need to ask the client about adding a 4th level in data category, then update all the rules to include the 4th level.

Comment: Is that customers have separate profiles or permission sets for Levels fields?

Comment: Yeah this sounds like a use-case for Sharing Rules but your situation would depend a lot on the current implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being Data Category Visibility settings on the profiles.